# Validate that textbox has numeric value in vb.net and compare value with database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation, textbox

enter image description hereI'm trying to validate a textbox where users will put an ID. The ID has to be numeric and at the same time compare to a valid ID in the database. When I was just validating for numeric, I didn't have any problems. But now that I have two conditions, my code doesn't work properly. Whenever I type in letters in the textbox and click a button, it gives me an error. The boolean is throwing me off lol. Below is my code:

Thank you in advance.

```
Protected Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow

    Dim Conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Computer;Initial Catalog=Catalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [tbl] WHERE [ID]=@Value", Conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtId.Text

    Conn.Open()
    Dim valueExistsInDB As Boolean = CBool(CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0)
    Conn.Close()

    If (IsNumeric(txtId.Text)) AndAlso valueExistsInDB = True AndAlso txtId.Text IsNot Nothing Then
        dt = GetDataTable("SELECT ID, LEFT(SANZ_ID, PATINDEX('%.%', SANZ_ID) -1) AS City, CASE WHEN ST_DIR_ID = 1 THEN 'NB' WHEN ST_DIR_ID = 2 THEN 'SB' WHEN ST_DIR_ID = 3 THEN 'EB' WHEN ST_DIR_ID = 4 THEN 'WB' END AS ST_DIR, STREET_OF_TRAVEL, CROSS_STREET, (SELECT TOP 1 CASE WHEN STATUS_ID = 1 THEN 'F' WHEN STATUS_ID = 2 THEN 'P' WHEN STATUS_ID = 3 THEN 'I' WHEN STATUS_ID = 4 THEN 'N' WHEN STATUS_ID = 5 THEN 'A' END FROM tbl where dbo.tbl.ID=ID) AS STATUS FROM tbl WHERE ID=" & txtId.Text)
        dr = dt.Rows(0)
        labelStreet.Text = dr("street_of_travel")
        labelCrossStreet.Text = dr("cross_street")
        labelCity.Text = dr("city")
        labelDir.Text = dr("st_dir")
        labelAda.Text = dr("STATUS")
        'dropdownStatus.SelectedValue=

        dropdownStatus.Visible = True
        txtNotes.Visible = True
        btnSave.Visible = True

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("ID not found! Please input a valid ID.")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `it gives me an error` What is the error?  Did you step through your code?  What line of code is causing the error?

Comment: Hi Rick, I posted some image links above to show you the error I get.

Comment: Also, this is how my other validation works (if ID is not in the database)
[link](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xta1/v/t1.0-9/10475225_1638249616393835_2438458783046276202_n.jpg?oh=a5732134a66ec5ecee07a43354a7c88a&oe=5574B9D0&__gda__=1434724397_39ed581a3c1be90fa9ed0c46333843d5)

And this is what happens if ID is valid.
[link](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-9/11083895_1638249619727168_4509698657429653504_n.jpg?oh=1cf39bca9efe655e5cff27ff5c8c9150&oe=557732ED&__gda__=1434201554_54ee91e66b9a661974014b7a8d2471e9)

Comment: If the ID needs to be numeric, why are you letting the user type letters?  Fix that problem and your code will probably work.

Comment: Asking to click on links to unknown sites will not help you. Post the error messages as text here updating your question

Comment: That's why I need to validate whatever they enter in the textbox is numeric. When they click Go and the ID says abcd, then there should be an error message that pops up saying that it's not a valid ID and I thought that's what I was doing because of my "If statement" above.

Comment: The error says: An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'asdf' to data type int.

Comment: OCTA_ID is numeric so your parameter in the first query should be numeric not NVarChar

Comment: Tried that. Got this error: An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

Comment: Check for IsNumeric() **before** you call ExecuteScaler().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ID is a numeric field then you should pass a numeric parameter not an NVarChar one

```
' First try to convert the input text to an integer '
' this should be done here before acting on the db '
Dim id As Integer
if Not Int32.TryParse(txtId.Text, id) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Error, not a valid number")
    return
End If

Dim cmdText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [tbl] WHERE [ID]=@Value"
Using Conn = New SqlConnection(....)
Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdText, Conn)
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
   Conn.Open()
   Dim valueExistsInDB = CBool(CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0)

   ' At this point you don't need anymore to check if the input value'
   ' is numeric and your if is more simple.....'
   if valueExistsInDB Then
   ......
   ... continue with your code ....

   Else
       MessageBox.Show("ID not found! Please input a valid ID.")
   End if
End Using
End Using
```